# Define functions collectively depending on an input parameter

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm developing a package, and one of its functions is `param`, which reads a rather big file and extract one of the parameters in there.

I have a few more functions, say `f1` and `f2`, and so on, whose definitions depend on the value of `param`. So straightforwardly I could write

```
param:=param=(*reading files*)
f1:=Switch[param, value1,def11, value2,def12,...]
f2:=Switch[param, value1,def21, value2,def22,...]
...
```

The advantage is that as soon as any one of the `f` functions is called, `param` will be set, so that when I call other `f` functions, I can save some time by avoiding reading and defining `param` again. Also, `param` will only be defined when it is necessary.

However this code is rather cumbersome, because I have to repeat `Switch` many times, and each of the `def`s is itself long. A better way could be

```
Switch[param,
  value1, f1:=def11;f2:=def21;...,
  value2, f1:=def12;f2:=def22;...,
  ...,
];
```

Now the code is in a more concise style, but the price is that `param` will be defined when loading the package, and unnecessarily slowing down the loading when none of the `f` functions are to be called.

My question is that, is there a better way to do the job, that takes both of the advantages that (1) `param` is only defined when necessary (when the `f` functions are called), and (2) the `f` functions can be define concisely in a collective way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A scheme like the following, using conditional definitions, should work. Here `Pause[3]` is just representative of the actual time-consuming process that loads the value of `param` in your package:

```
ClearAll[param, f1]
param := param = (Pause[3]; 1)

f1 := "f1 defined with param = 1" /; param == 1
f1 := "f1 defined with param = 2" /; param == 2
```

Now we can see that the first execution of `f1` will take longer and use the definition corresponding to the previously-loaded value of `param`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[f1]
(* {3.01633, "f1 defined with param = 1"} *)

AbsoluteTiming[f1]
(* {0.0000174, "f1 defined with param = 1"} *)
```

If, for some reason, the value of `param` changes, then the other function definition will be used:

```
param = 2;

AbsoluteTiming[f1]
(* {7.1*10^-6, "f1 defined with param = 2"} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any advantage of using ```Condition``` over ```Switch``` (the first implementation in the question)?

Comment: @H.Zhou To me, Condition results in cleaner and more readable code that fulfills the requirements you had set out.

Answer (score 2):

There are several considerations here, and I'm not sure what your priorities are. Do you want to be able to re-execute the code that sets `param`? Do you want to be able to handle the situation when `param` hasn't been defined/initialized? And so on...

I tend to avoid magic side effects, and instead make everything explicit, and then introduce the mappings/conditions on top of that.

```
f1Param[1] = "f1 is Alice";
f1Param[2] = "f1 is Bob";
f1Param[p_] := "f1: undefined for param = " <> ToString[p];

f2Param[1] = "f2 is Once";
f2Param[3] = "f2 is Thrice";
f2Param[_] = "f2 defaults to something";

f3Param[p_] := "f3 directly uses param = " <> ToString[p];

f1 := f1Param[SomeNamespace`Private`param];
f2 := f2Param[SomeNamespace`Private`param];
f3 := f3Param[SomeNamespace`Private`param];

SetParam[] := SomeNamespace`Private`param = (Pause[3]; RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}]);
```

Now you can

- Test your functions without needing access to the external dependency that defines `param`
- Override `param` as needed, but with a bit of safety
- Implement default, variable, or shared functionality cleanly
- Not hit a `Switch` every time you call a function
- See a static list of OwnValues/DownValues instead of them being rewritten by an initialization procedure
- Explicitly re-initialize `param` as needed

(These comments show a contrast with the original post, not MarcoB's solution, which shares most of these benefits.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is enlightening to me!